# unix - disable "su" for ssh'ers

Tags: ssh, sudo, su

I'd like to disable getting root at all for users who ssh in - including "sudo su" cause that's pretty much the same thing... Can this be done? Assume that I'M not ssh'ing in, and have physical access to the machine, but want to prevent other users from gaining root without physical access.

Comment: Not giving out `sudo` access is a good start.  Restricting to SSH Key Auth only is another good step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think to a generic way of having the same user able to do `sudo` in a graphical terminal (which is a virtual tty) and not on a `ssh` connection --- that in the end is just another kind of virtual tty.

What I can think as an approximate solution is:

1. have trusted users that can do `sudo`(1), call them `alpha` and `beta`
2. have users that can't do  `sudo`(1), call them `aleph` y `bet`

Now, forbid ssh login to `alpha` y `beta` using the `DenyUsers` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`:

```
DenyUsers alpha beta
```

If you want that the user `alpha` y `aleph` can share files, you can make them the same group or members of an additional group and adjust the file permissions accordingly.

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) Just a reminder: a user can do `sudo` if it's a member of the group `sudo` or `adm` (depending on Ubuntu version). To remove the ability for an user to do sudo:

```
gpasswd -d user sudo 
gpasswd -d user adm
```

and to enable it:

```
gpasswd -a user sudo 
gpasswd -a user adm
```

(one or the other --- check with `groups` which is the correct group in your system).

Comment: Thank you, the DenyUsers thing seems like it will work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require a fool-proof solution, you can make a wrapper for sudo that checks to see if you're logged in over SSH before running the real sudo.  Just create a `/usr/local/bin/sudo` script, mark it executable (`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sudo`), and add these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$SSH_CLIENT" != "" ]; then
    echo "remote sudo access is disabled" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

/usr/bin/sudo "$@"
```

Flaws:

1. while it works for `sudo`, it can be bypassed by calling `/usr/bin/sudo` directly
2. it relies on the contents of the `SSH_CLIENT` environment variable, so a user can bypass the restriction by clearing this environment variable

It's possible there's ways to address these issues, but if you just need something to stop your "typical" user then this should work.